# How to export raw strings for text in ticks to svg from matplotlib?

Tags: svg, matplotlib, label, tex, formatter

I use matplotlib to generate plots. In most cases it works as it is supposed to. But if I use TeX like text in ticks it behaves different from the text in other labels or annotations. I set rc.text.usetex=False and the labels are exported as raw text but the text of the ticks gets interpreted. In case of loglog plots or if other TeX commands like \frac are used, it results in plain numbers which are moved to their positions (e.g. superscript or fraction).

I use the following function to export svg graphics with raw strings. Afterwards, I use Inkscape to work on details and export it as PDF and TeX so all text is placed on the graphics with the put command.

```
def export_svg(plt=plt,svg_name='name'):
    plt.rc('text', usetex=False)
    plt.rc('text.latex', unicode = False)
    plt.rc('svg',fonttype = 'none')
    for blub in plt.findobj(match=plt.Text):
        blub.set_text(blub.get_text().replace('$','\$'))
    plt.savefig(svg_name + '.svg')
```

`axes.xaxis.get_ticklabels()[2].get_text()` yields `'$10^{1}$'`

`axes.xaxis.get_label().get_text()` yields `'\\$ x \\$'`. It becomes `'\$ x \$'` in the svg file and is exactly the format I need.

Has someone addressed this issue yet? I think I have to start with the Formatter class to get the backslash which is missing in the tick format.

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it does not only happen in case of loglog. The ticks are always exported without `\$ .. \$`.

My workaround is to create my own Formatter class:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class MyLogFormatterMathtext(plt.LogFormatter):
"""
Format values for log axis; using ``exponent = log_base(value)``
mark_r:
removed \mathdefault
escaped $ with \
"""

def __call__(self, x, pos=None):
    'Return the format for tick val *x* at position *pos*'
    b = self._base
    usetex = rcParams['text.usetex']

    # only label the decades
    if x == 0:
        if usetex:
            return '$0$'
        else:
            return '\$0\$' #'$\mathdefault{0}$'

    fx = math.log(abs(x)) / math.log(b)
    is_decade = is_close_to_int(fx)

    sign_string = '-' if x < 0 else ''

    # use string formatting of the base if it is not an integer
    if b % 1 == 0.0:
        base = '%d' % b
    else:
        base = '%s' % b

    if not is_decade and self.labelOnlyBase:
        return ''
    elif not is_decade:
        if usetex:
            return (r'\$%s%s^{%.2f}\$') % \
                                        (sign_string, base, fx)
        else:
            return (r'\$%s%s^{%.2f}\$') % \
                                        (sign_string, base, fx)
    else:
        if usetex:
            return (r'\$%s%s^{%d}\$') % (sign_string,
                                       base,
                                       nearest_long(fx))
        else:
            return (r'\$%s%s^{%d}\$') % (sign_string,
                                                     base,
                                                     nearest_long(fx))
```

I edited both cases `usetex==True` and `usetex==False` because the second one didn't yield the wanted result. It seems to me that the text in labels is treated different compared to the text in ticks.
So I have to use the standard `LogFormatterMathtext` if `usetex==True` to create the "familiar look". For the export to the svg format I use:

```
majorFormatter = MyLogFormatterMathtext()
axes.xaxis.set_major_formatter(majorFormatter)
```

I would prefer a more general solution but this one works as a makeshift. 
Feel free to ask questions or to comment on this solution.